# Xcode 5 - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, linker-errors

I am facing a linker error when running my source code,  I have attached a screenshot also.
I am new in iOS development and so I am not able to get the error. Any help would be much appreciated.[image]

Comment: I've checked the libraries. All have been added to build phases. When I force load the app..I am getting the actual error which is 'no such file or directory: 'AdSupport''. This library is required by Testflight also. I've this framework already added in my app but I am still getting this error

Comment: Don't include screen shots. They're pictures of words. Include the words. We're programmers.

Comment: Thanx developers for ur answers....... i got the solution for this problem and solved it well.........

Comment: You should therefore accept one of the answers of the people who helped you.

Comment: I have the same problem, can you share with us your solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check https://testflightapp.com/sdk/ios/doc/

A library was not found, that testflight needs.

Include that framework (lib) and you are done.

Comment: I've checked the libraries. All have been added to build phases. When I force load the app..I am getting the actual error which is no such file or directory: 'AdSupport'. This library is required by Testflight also. I've this framework already added in my app but I am still getting this error

Comment: Integrating 3rd party sometimes seems tricky :) You just missed something, maybe a flag or header file path. Best approach is to make a new project an try it again with documentation, step by step.

Comment: :) a common mistake is, when drag&drop the source files from demo app, you missed the "copy files to bundle", or you have to set a header search path. I often set the header search path, but in the wrong line. If you have a demo project from testflight, then compare with the settings. But the linker error i like i said, is a missed framework at the end. Thats all the help i can give you.

Answer (score 5):

Xcode has a bug in which it will double-escape quotes in a path. Note how the error on the screen you captured has ' \" ' and such in it. These are in error. Correct it so it looks like a path, instead.

I note also that it appears that your project path has spaces in it. While technically allowed, this is never a good idea. I'd suggest correcting that if you can.

Finally, notice that Xcode has included an absolute path that refers to your user directory. This will work for now, but not if you move the project. It's far better to make the path relative - search for this term if you're not familiar - to the root of your source code using the $SRCROOT variable. Then it is portable.

Comment: Thanx developers for ur answers....... i got the solution for this problem and solved it well.........

Comment: Yes, for me the solution was to replace \"$(SRCROOT)/../GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.0\" by $(SRCROOT)/../GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.0