# Worklight - XCode 5 compilation issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight Studio 6.0 to develop an iPad app. After i run the Build for Remote Server  build, i copied the zip file generated in the iPad environment and copied it over to a Macbook.

I unzip and opened the project via XCode 5, and build it, it gave me the error `Apple Mach-O Linker` . I also notice that under the `WorklightSDK` folder there's a file libWorklightStaticLibProject.a` is marked in red color, which i suspect means it failed to build the static library.

Any way to resolve this issue?

**Error log:**

```
ld: library not found for -lWorklightStaticLibProject
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (user -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: Hm, usually the error messages in Xcode are much more verbose than that. Are you sure that's all of it? It should look like in the screen shot here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954779/xcode-5-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-in --- please provide a similar image

Comment: The library built for the selected architectures should be placed at  one of the `Library search paths` that is set at the project and target build settings.

Comment: Yes, but generally and by default Worklight Studio generates an Xcode project that is already set-up; all that is then required is to run it in Xcode, which currently fails with the above error. Which is strange.

Comment: Sorry as it is weekend over here, the MacBook is with the client now. I'll have to wait til Monday to get back to you guys. Will post a screenshot when i got the chance.

Comment: update: i got this worked. It seems that Worklight Studio 6.0 cannot support XCode 5. After switching my Studio to version 6.1 and export, i'm able to build the app successfully. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ipohfly, Worklight 6.0.0.x does support Xcode 5.x; I am not sure what went wrong in your case. Anyway, please write this as an Answer to the question for now.

Comment: @IdanAdar Is it? I found in the IBM info center for version 6.0 it states XCode 4.5 while in 6.1 it states XCode 5.0, in the section `Preparations for using the mobile client` for the respective doc. I'll write an Answer for this question anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Xcode 4.5 and above. Worklight 6.0.0.x supports iOS 7.x and for that you must use Xcode 5. Thus, Xcode 5 is supported (I use it myself in 6.x)

Comment: I see.. hmm then i'm not sure why it happened to me. Not sure whether this is just my laptop problem or a wider issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get things done by upgrading my Worklight Studio to version 6.1. Not sure whether 6.0 can support XCode 5.0 or not, but here are the links to the info center page that points to the XCode versioning that i referred:

Worklight 6.0: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html

Worklight 6.1: https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html